# Sending the selected dropdown value from react js to django ORM

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework

I have frontend code in react that gives the selected value from dropdown. I want to send this value to the django views.py file so that I can use it in ORM for filtering.
The option values for dropdown are also coming from django backend.
The value selected in the dropdown is one of the Customer_Id s used for filter in ORM.

Following is the react code.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

class Select extends React.Component {
     static propTypes = {
     onChange: PropTypes.func,
     name: PropTypes.string,
     value: PropTypes.string,
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    error: false,
    value: props.default,
};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

render() {
   let dropdowns = this.props.state.dropdowns;
   let optionitems = dropdowns.map((dropdown) => {
        return(
          <option key={dropdown.auto_increment_id} value={dropdown.auto_increment_id}>
          {dropdown.customerName}
          </option>
        );
        }

  );

return (
  <div>
    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      Select Customer Name
      {optionitems}
    </select>
    <p>{this.state.value}</p> // want to send this value to views.py
  </div>
   );
  }
 }
export default Select;
```

Following is the views.py code:

```
from psiApp.models import Proactive,CustomersName
from psiApp.serializers import LogSerializer,CustSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class ListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Proactive.objects.all() 
    //Want something like: Proactive.objects.filter(Customer_id=value from react)
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
```

I hope the question is clear, I am new to working on react and django combined. Any ideas are appreciated!!
Sending the value from frontend to backend is something very new to me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It needs an ajax request. In case someone scrolls here.